# Paradox,shortest proof

Tags: number-theory, predicate-logic, proof-theory, paradoxes

I have read somewhere that the **shortest** proof of a certain formula in the language of natural numbers contains some kind of paradox. I cannot remember what this paradox was nor where I've read it. It may well be something like that
it is formally provable that even shorter proof exists.
Any help please?

Comment: That is Rosser's trick an improved version of Gödel's theorem. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick

Comment: That's it. Do you please have a non-wikipedia, pdf like detailed reference?

Comment: JBarkley Rosser, [Extensions of Some Theorems of Gödel and Church](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2269028?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents), JSL (1936)

Comment: Yes. And is there an even modern treatment of this paradox ? Either in a book or paper.

Comment: But it is not a paradox: it is an improved proof of [Gödel's incompleteness theorems theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems).